# Why do not I see the contents of my cardView?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-cardview

I have a cardView, but I can not see the content. I share part of the code, I hope to receive help. Thank you.
My project is executed directly on my cell phone. And only shows the cardView but without the content.

card_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"

    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"


            tools:src="@drawable/pika"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="20dp"
            tools:text="Paris"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ivann.cardview"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: Upvoted for question clarity. Remember to always close tags as mentioned by @Arpan Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to give `android:src` instead of `tool:src` for both imageView and textView

It might works!

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. The ``LinearLayout`` tag is not closed in the XML. That has to be fixed.

Comment: Ho works! Thank you very much for replying quickly. I'm starting in the Android world. regards!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_v"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pika"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="20dp"
                tools:text="Paris"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You are not closing your linear layout tag at the end